# How to use multiple User Provider in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony5

Now my web is used this provider and its working. But i need api token authentication. i need more user provider.

security:

```
providers:
    SecurityUserProvider:
        id: App\Security\SecurityUserProvider
```

Comment: are the api user other then the web user?
If the are the same you need only a other Authenticator

Comment: I created new App\Security\ApiTokenAuthenticator. But 1 problem occurred me. Api can't use username and password.

Comment: in my case:
If then the username and password are correct, create and return a token. 
i wanna do this. But i can't check username and password by api.

Answer (score 0):

Try following Workflow

Make an API Endpoint for getting a JWT-Token. Store this Token in the User Entity. If you want with a timestamp to expire that Token.

In the App\Security\ApiTokenAuthenticator you Check if the given Token is stored.
If yes => You know the User and you can check if token is valid with the Timestamp
If no => the Token invalid